# JNI and shared library

Tags: java-native-interface, mingw

Trying to create dll.
So first I created a .java file as follows:

```
class Main
{
    static 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("sample_dll");
    }

    static native void sritest();

    public static void main(String [] a)
    {
        sritest();
    }
}
```

Then I compile it with no error to .class.
Then using javah I created Main.h.

Then I write following code in c++.

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <Main.h>
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Main_sritest(JNIEnv *env,jobject obj)
{
    printf("hi");
}
```

Then I compiled this using MinGw by the following code

```
g++ -c sample_dll.cpp

g++ -shared -o sample_dll.dll sample_dll.o
```

Then I place this in java library path.
Then I run Main.java but the following exception occurs

> Unstatisfied link error; sritest ()V

Comment: how do you run the java program?

Comment: Have you tried setting the library path explicityly via `-Djava.library.path=.` ?

Comment: Some possibilities: The bitness of your java.exe and sample_dll.dll don't match. 2) The name of Java_Main_sritest isn't Java_Main_sritest. You might find out both using the [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) tool—try both the x86 and X64 versions. To see what java.exe is doing, use depend's Profile menu or use [ProcMon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Comment: When troubleshooting/developing with JNI, use these options on `java.exe -verbose:jni -Xcheck:jni`

Comment: See my answer . It worked . Thanks for everyone  help me.

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer . It is i do three mistakes. When compiling with c++ we must declare my jni function in extern "C"{} block. Second when compiling in minGW compiler we should use following code and implement include folder of jdk . The code now worked and my program runs smoothly without problem in jni.
The command line code for compiling .o to .dll code is after creating sample_dll.o we must do

```
g++ -Wall -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION -Wl,--kill-at -Ic:/path_of_include_folder_in_jdk_without_drive_letter -Ic:/path_of_win32_folder_in_include_folder_in_jdk_without_drive_letter -shared -o sample_dll.dll sample_dll.o
```

The last mistake is i want to include Main.h compiled by javah utlity that created from my java code.
This is done by

```
Javac Main.java
Javah Main
```

Then take the header file Main.h created and place it in the c++ compiler's include folder. That in my computer c:\minGW\include .
In c++ code add additional preprocessor

```
#include<Main.h>
```

All done create dll and place it in one of default java library path . The paths can be getted by using the following  function in java

```
System.out.println (System.getProperty ("java.library.path"));
```

Comment: I found answer . It worked. Thanks for everyone to help me.

Comment: @Devstr simply by using java Main from cimpiled java code